# Using jQuery, how do I select all instances of a class, when using a multiple class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a set of classes that are used multiple times on a page that I would like to add hover event handlers to, so that when one instance of the class is hovered over, all instances will display a  a "glow" affect.

I would like to avoid having to write out 10+ functions, so I have been trying to get it to work using jQuery's multiple selector API. e.g.

```
$(".r1,.r2,.r3,.r4,.r5,.r6,.r7,.r8,.r9,.r10").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("glow"); //All of r1, or r2 etc
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("glow"); //All of r1, or r2 etc
    }
);
```

My problem being that I can't figure out how to select all instances of the class, rather then just: $(this).

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter the entire collection based on the `className` property of the element that received the event.

```
var r_classes = $(".r1,.r2,.r3,.r4,.r5,.r6,.r7,.r8,.r9,.r10"),
    hovered;

r_classes.hover(
    function () {
        hovered = r_classes.filter( '.' + this.className ).addClass("glow"); 
    },
    function () {
        hovered.removeClass("glow"); //All of r1, or r2 etc
    }
);
```

When filtered, the filtered set is assigned to the `hovered` variable. This is so you don't need to repeat the filter.

Also, this assumes that the `r1,r2,...rn` class is the only one initially assigned to the element (before the `glow` class is added).

---

**EDIT:**

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pvQes/1/

Comment: `className` isn't a selector.

Comment: @kingjiv: Yes, I just added that to the end of my answer. If there's more than one initially, it will require a bit more work.

Comment: @patrick yeah sorry, saw that as soon as I commented, then deleted my comment before yours showed up.

Comment: @kingjiv: That's alright. There's always that little bit of a lag in the updates. :o)